# mongodb deleteOne for email in document array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have within a collection the following document model:

```
{
   "user":{
      "name":string,
      "email":string
   },
   "addres":{
      "direction":string,
      "country":string
   },
   "id":string
}
```

If you want to delete the document by id, no problem:

```
dataUser.deleteOne( {id: id});
```

What if I try it by email, it doesn't delete it:

```
dataUser.deleteOne( {"user": {email: email}})
```

I have tried other commands but it does not delete it either.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access object properties.

Check how [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P7sJffA4_F4) example doesn't find any document but [this one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zl9auHhf8xc) yes.

So you have to use:

```
dataUser.deleteOne( {"user.email": email})
```

Comment: Thank you J. F. ;)

Comment: No problem! Also if the issue has been solved, mark answer as accepted is appreciated.